# matplotlib plt.show() crashes in mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

So I'm trying to open plotted figures in my macbook running OSX 10.9.1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([25, 43, 65], [3500, 5500, 5800])
plt.show()
```

ipython crashes with plt.show() and outputs:
"Trace/BPT trap: 5"

and mac complains that:
Python quit unexpectedly while using the _macosx.so plug-in.

matplotlib (v1.4.x) was installed as part of the scipy superpack.
my python version is 2.7.5, came preinstalled on the machine

Does anyone have any ideas?

cheers

Heres part of the error report:

```
Process:         Python [14033]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         2.7.5 (2.7.5)
Build Info:      python-76000000000000~157
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [13998]
Responsible:     Terminal [13995]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so
PlugIn Identifier: _macosx.so
PlugIn Version:    ??? (0)

Date/Time:       2014-02-07 15:59:18.191 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  8B06B71F-C67A-9D9C-E43B-243601A5E06B

Sleep/Wake UUID: 1856EFBB-50E1-47A2-9B1A-86EA9D1BFA0A

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** __CFTypeCollectionRetain() called with NULL; likely a collection has been corrupted ***

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f309e8d __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 317
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f3096b8 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 424
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f311cdd CFBasicHashAddValue + 3709
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f34e94e CFDictionaryCreate + 142
4   _macosx.so                      0x000000010db7d596 GraphicsContext_get_text_width_height_descent + 225
5   org.python.python               0x000000010b2e714d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8080
6   org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
7   org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
8   org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
9   org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
10  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
11  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
12  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
13  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
14  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
15  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
16  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
17  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
18  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
19  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
20  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
21  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
22  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
23  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
24  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
25  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
26  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
27  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
28  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
29  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
30  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
31  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
32  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
33  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
34  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
35  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
36  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
37  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
38  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
39  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
40  org.python.python               0x000000010b2799a7 0x10b265000 + 84391
41  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
42  org.python.python               0x000000010b26f101 0x10b265000 + 41217
43  org.python.python               0x000000010b26f35a PyObject_CallMethod + 331
44  _macosx.so                      0x000000010db78267 -[View drawRect:] + 284
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90102399 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3748
46  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90100c0e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1799
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90100fea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
48  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90100fea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900fea50 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 841
50  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900fe201 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900fb209 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900da63a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900f4246 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1972
54  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900f37f0 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 786
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900f3470 -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 162
56  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff900e49f6 -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 51
57  _macosx.so                      0x000000010db7c63c FigureManager_show + 77
58  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e81ef PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12338
59  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
60  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
61  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
62  org.python.python               0x000000010b2799a7 0x10b265000 + 84391
63  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
64  org.python.python               0x000000010b2b3cad 0x10b265000 + 322733
65  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
66  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
67  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
68  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
69  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
70  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
71  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e937b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16830
72  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
73  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
74  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
75  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
76  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
77  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
78  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
79  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
80  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
81  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
82  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
83  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
84  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
85  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
86  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
87  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
88  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
89  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
90  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
91  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
92  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
93  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
94  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
95  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
96  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
97  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
98  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e4a24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
99  org.python.python               0x000000010b303c2c 0x10b265000 + 650284
100 org.python.python               0x000000010b303cd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137
101 org.python.python               0x000000010b303821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718
102 org.python.python               0x000000010b314363 Py_Main + 2995
103 libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8ea2a5fd start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94cd7716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02fc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   org.python.python               0x000000010b3125cc PyThread_acquire_lock + 104
3   org.python.python               0x000000010b2e478d PyEval_RestoreThread + 61
4   _sqlite3.so                     0x000000010bad1df9 pysqlite_step + 41
5   _sqlite3.so                     0x000000010bacd7e9 pysqlite_connection_commit + 140
6   org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
7   org.python.python               0x000000010b26f101 0x10b265000 + 41217
8   org.python.python               0x000000010b26f35a PyObject_CallMethod + 331
9   _sqlite3.so                     0x000000010bacea98 0x10bacb000 + 15000
10  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
11  org.python.python               0x000000010b26b7d1 PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs + 190
12  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e8933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14198
13  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
14  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
15  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
16  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
17  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
18  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
19  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
20  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
21  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
22  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
23  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
24  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
25  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
26  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
27  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
28  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
29  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e9395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
30  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
31  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb8c8 0x10b265000 + 551112
32  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
33  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb864 0x10b265000 + 551012
34  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
35  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb864 0x10b265000 + 551012
36  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e84d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
37  org.python.python               0x000000010b2e5093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
38  org.python.python               0x000000010b28c796 0x10b265000 + 161686
39  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
40  org.python.python               0x000000010b2799a7 0x10b265000 + 84391
41  org.python.python               0x000000010b26ef72 PyObject_Call + 101
42  org.python.python               0x000000010b2eb01f PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
43  org.python.python               0x000000010b315fa5 0x10b265000 + 724901
44  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02d899 _pthread_body + 138
45  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02d72a _pthread_start + 137
46  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f031fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94cd8662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9770943d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97709152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94cd7e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02ef08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f031fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94cd7e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02ef08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f031fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94cd7e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02ef08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f031fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94cd7e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f02ef08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f031fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff8f4b5a80  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000300  rdx: 0x0000000000000003
  rdi: 0x00007fff7ab0aeb0  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff5499a160  rsp: 0x00007fff5499a150
   r8: 0x00007f859d7b7230   r9: 0x00007fff7b7b3b10  r10: 0x00007fff949f801d  r11: 0x00007fff949f801b
  r12: 0x00007f859d7b7230  r13: 0x00007f859d7b7230  r14: 0x00007fff7b7b3b10  r15: 0x00007fff8f309d50
  rip: 0x00007fff8f309e8d  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00007f859d7b90a8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3
```

Comment: You have not provide enough information.  How did you install mpl? which version of python are you using (and how did you install it)? what version of osx?

Comment: If you just want to get it working, (without having to figure out why it is not working), try one of those `python` distributions around, such as `anaconda`.